# Как строку, в которой хранится время больше 24 часов, перевести в миллисекунды? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброго времени суток.

Можно ли как-то перевести строку, в которую записано время в часах:минутах:секундах (причем часов может быть больше 24) в тип времени, TimeSpan, например, или в миллисекунды?

Пробовал через TimeSpan.Parse, но это работает наполовину.

```
TimeSpan dtime = TimeSpan.Parse(dataGridView1[4, row].Value.ToString());
```

Суть в том, что если часов < 24, то все нормально. dtime = ЧЧ:ММ:СС.
Но если часов > 24, то dtime выглядит так: ДД.ЧЧ.ММ.СС

Т.е. если строка имеет формат: 25:12:22, то сохраняется она как 25.12:22:00, и не сказал бы, что это то, что нужно.

Comment: Разбивайте сами строку (`var parts = "25:12:22".Split(':')`), дальше создавайте новый `TimeSpan` а не парсите (`new TimeSpan(int.Parse(parts[0]), int.Parse(parts[1]), int.Parse(parts[2]))`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Спасибо, кажется, работает. Я правильно понимаю, parts - это массив, в котором хранятся часы (Parts[0]), минуты (Parts[1]) и секунды (Parts[2])?

Comment: Да, после `Split(':')` вам будет выдан массив, который разобьется по символу `:`, то есть, будет массив строк, в котором будет `[0] 25`, `[1] 12`, `[2] 22`, дальше их надо преобразовать из строки в число, ну а потом скормить `TimeSpan`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ещё раз, спасибо вам огромное!